# linear proposition quality(logic)

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

wondering about that. if a set of linear properties is defined as linear if it follows for every $a,b \in \sum$ $a \Rightarrow b$ or $b \Rightarrow a$

if i wanted to prove that a set of propositions I is defined such that: I only consists of a single elementary proposition p, and the only logical property is $\rightarrow$, how can i prove that I is linear according to the given definition(for every $a,b \in \sum$ $a \Rightarrow b$ or $b \Rightarrow a$)

and to help understand this concept better, if i wanted to show that if $\sum$ is a set of linear propositions and each proposition in $\sum$ has a model in which the proposition holds true, how can i show that there exists a model for $\sum$?

my attempt:

for the first: we'll check for a single proposition: if I consists only oneproposition p such that the only logical operator is $\rightarrow$ that means that for every $a,b \in \sum$ $a \Rightarrow b$ or $b \Rightarrow a$. we'll assume it holds true for every n amount of elements in $\sum$ ad we'll check for validity for n+1 number of elements. here i have my problem - if we have more than two elements(n+1 in this case), how can we deduct that I will be linear, at about infinite elements, i think that there is a case where it might be problematic.

for the second: as far as i understand, if we can show that if $\sum$ is linear aמd each poperty in $\sum$ has a model in which the proposition is true, we can deduct that $\sum$ is not bounded, and then using the induction i couldn't yet prove, we can deduct that if all of the above holds true, then there exists a model for $\sum$.

please help me fix and improve that, using the correct mathmatical writing or sohw me what i've done wrong.

thank you very much!

Comment: Is $\Sigma$ assumed to be finite? Also, isn't the first case about $\Sigma=I=\{p\} $?  Then it is trivial, as picking two elements $a, b$ from it must yield $a=b=p$.

Comment: i don't understand. why does it have to yield a=b=p? can't it be otherwise? if we give an infinite set, can't we make it so that for every $a \in sum$ exists $b\in sum$ so that $a \not\Rightarrow b$?